# Puppeteer not rendering images stored on AWS S3

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer on Nodejs to render a PDF document via a page. However, it seems like images hosted on AWS S3 cannot be loaded, whereas images stored locally on the server itself loads fine.

I tried adding both `waitUntil: "networkidle0"` and `waitUntil: "networkidle1"` but it still does not work. I also tried adding `printBackground: true` too.

[The images loads perfectly fine on the page as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw9Ft.png)

[However, on the PDF generated by Puppeteer, the images does not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJLSQ.png)

This is my code:

```
 (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
      authorization: req.session.token
    });

    await page.goto(config.url + "/project/download/" + permalink, {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0"
    });

    const buffer = await page.pdf({
      filename: permalink + "_ProjectBrief" + ".pdf",
      format: "A4",
      margin: {
        top: 60,
        bottom: 60,
        left: 60,
        right: 50
      },
    });
    res.type("application/pdf");
    res.send(buffer);
    await browser.close();
  })();
```

Any idea what should I do to get over this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the issue.

After adding `headless: false` to

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ["--no-sandbox"]
    });
```

I realised that the images did not load because of a 400 error. My hypothesis is that Chromium did not have enough time to download the images and thus throwing this error.

What I did was to edit the HTML file that I want Puppeteer to render, adding this code to it:

```
data.ProjectImages.forEach(e => {
   window.open(e.imageUrl, '_blank');
});
```

What this does is that it opens up the images via its URL onto a new tab. This ensures that the images are downloaded to the Chromium instance (Puppeteer runs Chromium).

The rendered PDF can now display the images.